# unable to add a variable into an object key name inside V-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a dynamic form inside a table that increases and decreases it's rows when a user clicks  button in my `vue` app. The table looks like:

```
<table class="stripped centered">
    <pre>{{ form }}</pre>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th><a @click="addRow(false) " class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-3 white-text">Add row</a></th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="body-rows">
       <tr v-for="(row, index) in tableRows" :key="JSON.stringify(row)">
           <td colspan="8">
               <table>
                   <tr>
                       <td><a @click.prevent="deleteRow(index)" class="waves-effect waves-light btn red darken-3 white-text"><i class="material-icons left">delete</i></a></td>
                       <td><input v-model="form['item_no'+row]" class="item-no" type="number" step="0.001" placeholder="Item no"></td>
                       <td><a  @click="addRow(true) "  class="add-sub waves-effect waves-light btn teal darken-3 white-text"><i class="material-icons left">add</i>sub</a></td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
           </td>          
       </tr>
   </tbody>             
</table>
```

And in the `<script>` I have the following:

```
data(){
    return{
        currentRows: 0,
        tableRows: [],
        inputData: [],
        isCurrentSub: false,
        form: {}
   }
},
methods:{
    addRow(isSUb){
        this.currentRows++
        this.tableRows.push(this.currentRows)
        var tempObj = {}
        console.log(this.currentRows);
        console.log(this.form['item_no'+this.currentRows]);

        if(isSUb){
            this.isCurrentSub = true
            tempObj['sub_item_no-'+this.currentRows] = this.form['item_no'+this.currentRows]

        }

        else{
            tempObj['item_no-'+this.currentRows] = this.form['item_no']

        }

        this.inputData.push(tempObj)
    },
```

As you see in the above code I am trying to get the value of the input and shove it into the `inputData` to process it later. The problem with this is `this.form['item_no'+this.currentRows]` is not storing the value and `console.log(this.form['item_no'+this.currentRows])` is returning `undefined`. And `console.log(this.currentRows);` shows the number of rows that are currently in the table. But `<pre>{{ form }}</pre>` is showing the correct values in the `UI`. I have added a sandbox version of this which is not working at all https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-leftpad-1pjes?file=/src/App.vue. This code works fine on my local app. Is there any other way to do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: @palaѕн I added my code into the sandbox but it is not rendering at all. The exact code is rendering fine in my local environment.

Comment: "_The problem with this is this.form['item_no'+this.currentRows] is not storing the value and console.log(this.form['item_no'+this.currentRows]) is returning 'undefined'_" Where did you put `console.log(this.form['item_no'+this.currentRows])` in your code? Update you post with that.

Comment: @palaѕн Sorry I forgot to include that. I have edited my question.

Comment: @palaѕн I am setting it in `v-model` in the table. And it works if I just do `this.form['item_no']` and set `v-model= "form['item_no']"`. And I get the value of the field when I log it. The problem comes when I try to concatenate `row` in `v-model`.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. Just add `<pre>{{ form }}</pre>` inside template below table and click on add row button to add two rows, then change value for input box and the template is showing correct value in UI like `{
  "item_no1": "0.001",
  "item_no2": "0.002"
}`

Comment: @palaѕн Yes but I can not get the values inside the script. I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Can you tell me where are you trying to access the `form` model values and how? Update you post with that.

Comment: I tried logging it to console when `addRow` method is called. It shows undefined. I am going to edit the post with this too.

Comment: That time value will be undefined as nothing has changed. You just added the controls to the UI. Model value will only update when you change it in the UI or manually set those values like `this.form['item_no'+this.currentRows] = 0.002
      console.log(this.form['item_no'+this.currentRows]);`

Comment: Then you can see console log is showing data.

Comment: Yes that is a problem too. But I can't see the values even if I change the value of the `input`. But if I change `form['item_no'+row]` to  `form['item_no']` and `form['item_no'+this.currentRows]` to `form['item_no']` it shows me the value

Comment: I can see the values properly. Click on add row button to add two rows, then change the value for the input box and the template is showing correct value in UI  [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-forest-uj5pn)

Comment: Should I create an issue on Github?

Comment: Why you need to create an issue for this when it is working fine?

Comment: check the demo on the sandbox logging the value still don't work

Comment: You mean console log inside add row method?

Comment: Yes don't you think if `console.log(this.form["item_no" + this.currentRows])` doesn't work `console.log(this.form["item_no" ])` shouldn't work too?

Comment: this.form["item_no" ] works becuse it gets value assigned after first add row click and form object key here is static but in case this.form["item_no" + this.currentRows] key is not static so you don't get the values always.

Comment: understand this var obj = {} obj["key"] = 1 then console.log( obj["key"] ) works, then again obj["key"] = 2 then console.log( obj["key"] ) works again

Comment: But, var obj = {} obj["key1"] = 1 then console.log( obj["key2"] ) does not works, then again obj["key2"] = 2 then console.log( obj["key3"] ) also not works.

Comment: Okay I understand now. Is there any other way to store this input values in a way I could retrieve them?